# jupyter notebook on windows with anaconda kernel

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook

How can I change the kernel of Jupyter notebook. I'm using anaconda distribution on windows. 
I need  Calysto Scheme kernel from here 
https://github.com/Calysto/calysto_scheme

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to:

```
pip install calysto_scheme
python -m calysto_scheme install
```